Extracting json array in Postgres
My Postgres database contains a list of json objects as records.  I am trying to extract an array from the record, and Postgres does not seem to like what I'm proposing.
Here's an example of a record.
{
  "id": 1,
  "record": [
    {
      "field1": "data1",
      "field2": "data2"
    },
    {
      "field1": "data3",
      "field2": "data4"
    }
  ]
}

The expected output is



id
field1
field2




1
data1
data2


1
data3
data4



Here is the sample code I've been experimenting with.  I tried unnest,
with raw_data as (
    select '{ "id" : 1, "record" : [   { "field1" : "data1" , "field2":"data2"},  { "field1" : "data3" , "field2":"data4"}  ] }'::json json_data
    union all
    select '{ "id" : 2,"record" : [   { "field1" : "data1" , "field2":"data2"},  { "field1" : "data3" , "field2":"data4"}  ] }'::json as json_data
)

 
SELECT
    json_data->>'id' as id,
    record.field1           as field1,
    record.field2           as field2
FROM
    raw_data,
    unnest(json_data.record) as record

The use of json_to_recordset also did not work.

select
    json_data->>'id' as id,
    record.field1,
    record.field2,
from
    raw_data,
    json_to_recordset(json_data->>'record') record
    (
        field1 text,
        field2 text
    )

Any advice on this issue would be greatly appreciated.


unnest is a Postgres array function, not a json function. 2) json_to_recordset needs to be unpacked with as t(fldname datatype, ...)


"Postgres does not seem to like what I'm proposing", "json_to_recordset also did not work" - what is the concrete error message you are getting? Or does it just not return the desired result?

json_data->>'record' returns text. You'll want json_data->'record' instead to pass to json_to_recordset

@AdrianKlaver OP is doing the unpacking with aliases just fine

Your second attempt is almost there except that (1) json_data->>'record' returns text and not JSON so json_to_recordset can not work as @Bergi commented, use json_data->'record' instead and (2) there is an extra comma after record.field2. Fixed these two and it works fine.
with raw_data(json_data) as 
(
 values 
  ('{"id": 1,"record": [{"field1": "data1","field2": "data2"},{"field1": "data3","field2": "data4"}]}'::json),
  ('{"id": 2,"record": [{"field1": "data5","field2": "data6"},{"field1": "data7","field2": "data8"}]}')
)
select
    json_data->>'id' as id,
    record.field1,
    record.field2
from
    raw_data,
    json_to_recordset(json_data->'record') record
    (
        field1 text,
        field2 text
    )




id
field1
field2




1
data1
data2


1
data3
data4


2
data5
data6


2
data7
data8



